# Specific behaviour wanted when loading and displaying an image in an NSScrollView (Mac OS X)

Tags: objective-c, nsview, nsscrollview

I am very unexperienced and rather new to Objective-C and I'd like to ask a methodical question. What I want to do is:

1. Load a user provided image to show on the screen. The user should be
   able to zoom. So it seems best for me to use a NSScrollView to draw
   the image. I have some other demands about the behavior
2. When the image is loaded, it should fit the NSScrollView without
   being stretched in either direction.
3. When the user now changes the size of the NSScrollView (via changing
   the size of the window) the image should be resized appropriately.
4. If the user at some point zooms the image, it shall not be resized
   when changing the size of the NSScrollView. If the image is zoomed
   to fit into the NSScrollView (means like when loaded) it should be
   resized again when changing the size of the NSScrollView. I think
   this is the same behavior as in Apple's preview app.

I guess this is easy to achieve for an experienced programmer, but I have some issues. Here's what I have tried.

I load the image via

```
[[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imagePathStr];
```

on a button click. I am also able that it is displayed to fit nicely (on load) into the NSScrollView by changing the size of the image before drawing it. But I can't get the behavior right on resizing or zoom (I use the NSScrollView biuld-in zoom ability). Can someone provide some kind of list of key points that needed to be executed to achieve what I want? Or do someone rather see my explicit code to tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you ever get a decent implementation of this? Want to provide a small sample project/code? :) I need to do something similiar and came across your question..

Comment: @Cutetare Unfortunately not. I do have now something that comes closer but it is not working 100% as described (point 3 and 4 is not realized). Although I think the automatic resizing is can be done via a views `setAutoresizingMask`.